# installing app-release.apk to phone

Tags: android

I have a problem while installing the app-release.apk to my phone (Galaxy J5 2016, Android 6.0.1).
I have developed an application using Android Studio and tried to release it to the user with the .apk file.
but unfortunately, I encounter the below problems while install:

1. I cannot uninstall the debug version from android studio in my
   phone.
2. There is an error of 'Package installer has stopped' whenever
   I want to install it to my phone and my friends phone.

Note that I have signed the application in android studio.

Comment: Please using the Android studio log viewer to get the error message first.
Just filter these error message when try to uninstall the apk, and try to install the apk, the log will help you to understand what is the problem.

Comment: how can i open the log viewer? sorry for any inconvenience

Comment: Please install the android debug bridge https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html and the corresponding OEM driver. And then run the "adb logcat" command to capture the error message. Finally, post it  in your question again.

Comment: will do. thank you

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when app is not installed properly via ADB.

Go to your Phone Settings -> Apps -> Select your app and Uninstall for all users.

Try to run again from Android Studio to phone.

Comment: the problem is that I cannot uninstall debug version of the application from my phone. Is there any other way for me to uninstall it?

Comment: Factory reset will do, but i dont think you would choose that option,